# How to add superscript to text in data frame?

Tags: r

I am trying to get in the habit of making tables in R rather than "by hand" in MS Excel. How can I make my text superscripted within a data frame?

Example Data:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df)[1:4] <- c("Variable","Location 1","Location 2","p-value")
df$Variable <- c("Variable 1 (mg L<sup> -1</sup>)",
                 "Variable 2 (g kg<sup> -1</sup>)",
                 "Variable 3 (ppt)")
View(df)
```

I have also tried the following notation but it also did not work.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df)[1:4] <- c("Variable","Location 1","Location 2","p-value")
df$Variable <- c(expression(paste("Variable 1 (mg   ",  L^-1,")")),
                 expression(paste("Variable 2 (g   ",  kg^-1,")")),
                 "Variable 3 (ppt)")
View(df)
```

Comment: Where are you displaying these tables? What packages are you using to create the tables?

Comment: @GregorThomas This is all being done in base Rstudio

Comment: So you're hoping to have the sub/superscripts displayed in the console when you print the data frame?

Comment: @GregorThomas I'm hoping that when I submit `View(df)` I will see the data frame with the notation.

Comment: I doubt there is such functionality using formatting--I think the intention of View is to allow an analyst to do a quick inspection of data, not to produce presentation-ready tables. You could use unicode characters directly, `View(data.frame(x = c("½", "mg L⁻¹")))` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better to use `kableExtra`, `view()` isn't really provided for tables. There is quite a [comprehensive documentation on it here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html), it is quite useful.

```
library(kableExtra)
kbl(df, escape=F)
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know about the `kableExtra` package but `df %>%  kbl(escape = F) %>% kable_styling()` is ultimately what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode characters to the extent that they are supported.  This worked for me in the Rgui R console on Windows using R 4.2.1 .

```
df <- data.frame(Variable = c("Variable 1 (mg L\u207b\u00b9)",
                              "Variable 2 (g kg\u207b\u00b9)",
                              "Variable 3 (ppt)"))
df$"Location 1" <- df$"Location 2" <- df$pvalue <- NA

df
```

giving:

```
             Variable Location 1 Location 2  pvalue
1 Variable 1 (mg L⁻¹)         NA         NA      NA
2 Variable 2 (g kg⁻¹)         NA         NA      NA
3    Variable 3 (ppt)         NA         NA      NA
```